# Values sent to PHP via POST are all empty strings

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have the following form:

```
<FORM action="http://url.to.mysite.com/doc.php" method="post">
    <INPUT type="text" id="name">
    <INPUT type="text" id="id">
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Send">
    </P>
 </FORM>
```

Unfortunately, whatever is typed into the text fields, the PHP script receives only empty strings in every `$_POST` variable. All of the variables are set, just empty. What can be the cause of that?

Comment: there are no "name" attributes in the form

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP $_POST not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854205/php-post-not-working)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing the name properties in your html:

```
<FORM action="http://url.to.mysite.com/doc.php" method="post">
    <INPUT type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <INPUT type="text" name="id" id="id">
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Send">
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 4):

Only form elements with a `name` attribute will be sent to the PHP script (same with POST)
Try this:

```
<form action="http://url.to.mysite.com/doc.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the name attribute to your input tags.  Example: `<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />`