# How to get the data from input without attribute name?

Tags: php

I read [$_POST is empty after form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854205/php-post-not-working/854212#854212) topic and I wondered how to get the data from input without attribute name?

```
    <input type="text" >


var_dump($_REQUEST)//empty
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input')) //empty
```

Comment: If an HTML `<input>` doesn't have a `name` it won't be passed to the querystring or the POST data - there will be no way to retrieve it from PHP.

Comment: Maybe this one could help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543848/does-form-data-still-transfer-if-the-input-tag-has-no-name

Comment: Thanks MIKE and RENOCOR

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the form should be specified its name. If not, you cannot get it from the server-side.

However, the form without name is also valid in `HTML5`. The reason is that you might sometimes want to use for `form submission via AJAX or Javascript app`. In many cases