# ajaxForm is sending empty POST when submit from dynamically built form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post, ajaxform

Submitting a file with `ajaxSubmit()` works fine when the form is hard-coded. But the data received by the server is empty when the form is created dynamically.

**This version works**

HTML

```
<form id='file_upload_form' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
<input type="file" id='myfile' name="myfile" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<div id='status'> </div>
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#file_upload_form").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit({
            target: '#status'
        });
    });
});
```

Debuggin in `.on("submit"...` , `jQuery(this).formSerialize()` yields `"myfile=%5Bobject+File%5D"`

**But this version using a dynamically created form sends empty data**

HTML

```
<div id='parent_elem_div'> </div>
<div id='status'> </div>
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var parent_elem = jQuery('#parent_elem_div');

    var new_form_elem = build_form();
    parent_elem.append(new_form_elem);
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#file_upload_form").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit({
            target: '#status'
        });
    });
});
```

But here, debuggin in `.on("submit"...` , `jQuery(this).formSerialize()` yields `""`.

This function builds the form...

```
//
function build_form (){
    var new_inner_div_elem = document.createElement('div');
    new_inner_div_elem.id = 'parent_elem_div';

    var upload_form = document.createElement('form');
    upload_form.id = 'file_upload_form';
    upload_form.action = '/upload';
    upload_form.method = 'POST';
    upload_form.enctype="multipart/form-data";

    var file_input = document.createElement('input');
    file_input.type = 'file';
    file_input.id = 'file_upload_input';

    var file_upload_submit = document.createElement('input');
    file_upload_submit.type = 'submit'; 

    upload_form.appendChild(file_input);
    upload_form.appendChild(file_upload_submit);

    new_inner_div_elem.appendChild(upload_form);
    return new_inner_div_elem;
}
```

Comment: When form created dinamically, does on submit your code in `jQuery("#file_upload_form").on("submit"...` trigger at all?

Comment: There is no such function as `build_file_upload_form` defined. And I'm not sure, you can upload files like that.

Comment: Refactoring typo.Fixed.

Comment: @hRvoed Yes in both cases, the `.on('submit'...` triggers. (And my server receives a Request in both cases. But in the latter, the POST contents is empty.)

Comment: I was hoping not to over-complicate with the server code, since it doesn't change, but if you want to I will clarify that.

Comment: I know the server receives a Request, but I was wondering, does this `e.preventDefault();` triggers. If so...it really is strange because I dont see the difference

Comment: Ok, $_POST is empty that is fine, what about $_FILES ? This should be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! Here it go, in your code:

```
var file_input = document.createElement('input');
file_input.type = 'file';
file_input.id = 'file_upload_input';
```

This is missing:

```
file_input.attr('name', 'myfile');
```

This is the only part that your HTML form has, and dynamical doesn't, so I guess that's the trick

> If an HTML  doesn't have a name it won't be passed to the
>   querystring or the POST data - there will be no way to retrieve it
>   from PHP
>   This is from [here - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412787/how-to-get-the-data-from-input-without-attribute-name)